# How do I make 100 = 1? (explanation within)

Tags: math, formula, python-3.6

Right now I have a code that can find the number of combinations of a sum of a value using numbers greater than zero and less than the value. 
I need to alter the value in order to expand the combinations so that they include more than just the value.

For example:
    The number 10 yields the results:
        [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 7], 
        [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], 
        [1, 9], [2, 3, 5], [2, 8], 
        [3, 7], [4, 6]
    But I need to expand this to including any number that collapses to 1 as     well. Because in essence, I need 100 = n in that the sum of the individual numbers within the digits = n. So in this case 100 = 1 because 100 --> 1+0+0 = 1
Therefore the number 1999 will also be a valid combination to list for value = 100 because 1999 = 1+9+9+9 = 28, and 28 = 2+8 = 10, and 10 = 1+0 = 1

Now I realize that this will yield an infinite series of combinations, so I will need to set limits to the range I want to acquire data for. This is the current code I am using to find my combinations.

```
def a(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    def _a(idx, l, r, t, w):
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u if w else (u + 1), l + [lst[u]], r, t, w)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target, with_replacement)

for val in range(100,101):
    s = range(1, val)
    solutions = a(s, val)
    print(solutions)
    print('Value:', val, "Combinations", len(solutions))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question for us?

Comment: I'm trying to find combinations for a number which collapses to a single integer. So n = 124 would collapse to 7 because the sum of the integers within the number = 7, 1+2+4=7. In this case the number 124 would be a valid combination for n = 7. Another aacceptable combination would be 601 because the integers add up to 7, 6+0+1 = 7. The Same would go for a larger number, just with extra steps, 1285 is an acceptable combination because 1+2+8+5 = 16, and then form there 1+6 = 7.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do. But what are you asking us? Do you want us to write code for you that accomplishes your purpose or do you have a more specific question?

Comment: More specifically my question is, how do I take a value like 123 and seperate the integers within it '1', '2', '3' so that I can then add them together and have an output that is the sum, in this case 7. And i want to repeat this process until I get to a single digit. So if it is a larger number, 1234, when i seperate the integers and add them together they will equal 11, from there I want to repeat the process again so I get 2.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple issues.

**To repeatedly add the decimal digits of an integer** until you end with a single digit, you could use this code.

```
d = val
while d > 9:
    d = sum(int(c) for c in str(d))
```

This acts in just the way you describe. However, there is an easier way. Repeatedly adding the decimal digits of a number is called [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) and results in the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of the number. This almost equals the remainder of the number when divided by nine, except that you want to get a result of `9` rather than `1`. So easier and faster code is

```
d = val % 9
if d == 0:
    d == 9
```

or perhaps the shorter but trickier

```
d = (val - 1) % 9 + 1
```

or the even-more-tricky

```
d = val % 9 or 9
```

**To find all numbers that end up at `7`** (for example, or any digit from `1` to `9`) you just want all numbers with the remainder `7` when divided by `9`. So start at `7` and keep adding `9` and you get all such values.

The approach you are using to find all partitions of `7` then arranging them into numbers is much more complicated and slower than necessary.

**To find all numbers that end up at `16`** (for example, or any integer greater than `9`) your current approach may be best. It is difficult otherwise to avoid the numbers that directly add to `7` or to `25` without going through `16`. If this is really what you mean, say so in your question and we can look at this situation further.