# How do I add pieces of lists together all at once and use a while statement to replace my 'if' statement?

Tags: python, list, math, python-3.6

Right now I have each piece[] of the list individually converted to int() and then I add them together one by one. I know I'm using a very inefficient method and was hoping for some feedback on how I should go about cleaning this up.

The goal is to take a number like 123 and separating each digit and then adding them together to reach a single digit, 6. The if statement is used so that if I use a larger number like 655 and end up with 16 the number will be separated once again to '1', '6' and summed again to equal 7, a single digit.

Although right now I am limited to numbers of length 3 becasue I don't know how to convert entire strings.

```
val = input('Enter Value:')
#val = int(val)

#individual value
ival = list(val)
iv0 = int(ival[0])
iv1 = int(ival[1])
iv2 = int(ival[2])
print(iv2)


ivs = (iv0+iv1+iv2)
print(ivs)

if ivs > 9:
    ivs = str(ivs)
    ivss = list(ivs)
    fiv0 = int(ivss[0])
    fiv1 = int(ivss[1])
    fivs = (fiv0+fiv1)
    print(fivs)
    if fivs > 9:
        fivs = str(fivs)
        ivss = list(fivs)
        fiv0 = int(ivss[0])
        fiv1 = int(ivss[1])
        fivs = (fiv0+fiv1)
        print(fivs)
else:
    print(ivs)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this arithmetically, but I think the easiest way to do it is by getting the string representation of the number and working with that.

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = sum(int(c) for c in str(n))
    if s > 9:
        return sum_digits(s)
    return s
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this code.

```
d = val
while d > 9:
    d = sum(int(c) for c in str(d))
```

This acts in just the way you describe. However, there is an easier way. Repeatedly adding the decimal digits of a number is called [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) and results in the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of the number. This almost equals the remainder of the number when divided by nine, except that you want to get a result of `9` rather than `0`. So easier and faster code is

```
d = val % 9
if d == 0:
    d = 9
```

or perhaps the shorter but trickier

```
d = (val - 1) % 9 + 1
```

or the even-more-tricky

```
d = val % 9 or 9
```

(Note that I included this information in an answer I gave to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867325/how-do-i-make-100-1-explanation-within/46876704#46876704) from you.)

Comment: @MaximTitarenko: You are right. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. It is corrected now.

Comment: thanks for your answer to the question! What a smart approach!

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
def maths(given_value):
    retval = 0
    for i in given_value:
        retval += int(i)
    return retval

value = raw_input("enter a number: ")
```